# How to get name of model linked from another model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, associations

I have set up 2 models in Rails:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :platforms
end
```

and

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :url, :country
    validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5 }
    validates :url, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 5 }
    belongs_to  :categories
end
```

This is my platform controller :

```
class PlatformsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /platforms
  # GET /platforms.json
  def index
    @platforms = Platform.all
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @platforms }
    end
  end

  # GET /platforms/1
  # GET /platforms/1.json
  def show
    @platform = Platform.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Platform.categories

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @platform }
    end
  end

  # GET /platforms/new
  # GET /platforms/new.json
  def new
    @platform = Platform.new
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @platform }
    end
  end

  # GET /platforms/1/edit
  def edit
    @platform = Platform.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.find(:all)
  end

  # POST /platforms
  # POST /platforms.json
  def create
    @platform = Platform.new(params[:platform])
    #@categories = Category.new(params[:name])
    @categories = @platform.categories.create(params[:categories])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @platform.save
        format.html { redirect_to @platform, notice: 'Platform was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @platform, status: :created, location: @platform }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @platform.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /platforms/1
  # PUT /platforms/1.json
  def update
    @platform = Platform.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @platform.update_attributes(params[:platform])
        format.html { redirect_to @platform, notice: 'Platform was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @platform.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /platforms/1
  # DELETE /platforms/1.json
  def destroy
    @platform = Platform.find(params[:id])
    @platform.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to platforms_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I do not understand what I do wrong, but it doesnt correctly assign categories to platforms, and also in the platforms index view, when I try to use :

```
<%= platform.categories  %>
```

it gives me error cannot find Category with id= "and here the respective id"

I am really confused since I followed tutorial for this one.

I use Rails 3.2.8

Comment: I also get this : ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PlatformsController#update

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_id

Comment: Can a platform belong to many categories? If so you might want to check out `has_and_belongs_to` [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: No, one platform can belong only to 1 category, but 1 category can have many platforms.

Comment: Ok, then first you need to fix the Category association in your Product model.

`belongs_to: category`

Belongs to associations are written in singular form.

Comment: Also, you can't create categories from a platform instance because of the `belong_to` association. You can however create platforms from a category because of the `has_many` association.

Comment: If I do the changes @manishval proposed, in the index view I see categories next to platforms looking something like this : #<Category:0x007f9deac6d3f8> and #<Category:0x007f9deb8f5878>, but when I edit view to show platform.category.name it crashes the view with error : undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @manishval What do you mean with "You can however create platforms from a category because of the has_many association." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your view, I can't say for sure what it is you're trying to do exactly. Most importantly, what is in your params[:categories] hash? Given the name, it sounds like you intended for it to be multiple categories. However, your code is written as if you intended it to be a single set of attributes which describe one `Category`.

Since I can't say for sure what you *want* to do, I'll answer your question by explaining what you *are* doing. Maybe that will help you figure out how to fix it.

Your `create` code currently looks like this:

```
# POST /platforms
# POST /platforms.json
def create
  @platform = Platform.new(params[:platform])
  #@categories = Category.new(params[:name])
  @categories = @platform.categories.create(params[:categories])
```

The first line creates the new `Platform` and is easy. Skipping over the comment to the third line. This is probably what's tripping you up.

You are selecting the associations for your newly created `Platform` and trying to create a new category with attributes as stored in the `params[:categories]` hash. I'm afraid this is not allowed. (I think it throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` exception, but I could be wrong.) You can not `create` on a `@platform` which hasn't been persisted yet. Instead, I think you want `build`.

Here is the relevant documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

The difference between `create` and `build` is that `build` just sets up the association without actually saving it to the database yet. `create` saves it immediately. The nice thing about `build` is that you don't actually have to save it yourself. It tags along for free when you call `@platform.save` or `@platform.update_attributes`. Also, `save` is automatically wrapped in a transaction, so it won't create the new `Category` if it fails to create the new `Platform` for whatever reason.

The next interesting thing is that you are assigning the result of your create to `@categories`. I don't think this is what you want either. You don't need to save the new `Category` because it tags along with your `@platform`. However, if the `save` of the platform fails, then you are going to re-render your `new` view with this value of `@categories` whereas in `new` you set `@categories = Category.all`. This could certainly cause some confusion on the `new` view after a failed `create`.

In summary, I think your `create` code should look something like the following.

```
# POST /platforms
# POST /platforms.json
def create
  @platform = Platform.new(params[:platform])
  @platform.categories.build(params[:categories])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @platform.save
      format.html { redirect_to @platform, notice: 'Platform was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @platform, status: :created, location: @platform }
    else
      @categories = Category.all
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @platform.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

If you're `params[:categories]` is not a hash of category attributes and is actually a comma delimited string of category names, then you would want to do something like the following instead of my second line above:

```
params[:categories].split(",").each do |category|
  @project.categories.build(name: category)
end
```

You may also want to check out `accepts_nested_attributes_for` which can DRY out your controller even more.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

I hope that helps.